# jQuery ui menu icon(for submenu) is not visible

Tags: jquery, css

I have a common jQuery ui menu used in my page. Here is my menu script

```
<ul id="ulMenu-Config" >
       <li>
           <a id="aConfig" href="#aConfig"></a>
           <ul>
                <li><a id="aExportConfig" href="#aExportConfig"></a></li>
                <li><a id="aImportConfig" href="#aImportConfig"></a></li>
                <li><a id="aClearConfig" href="#aClearConfig"></a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
 </ul>
```

and here is my code for menu

```
$('#ulMenu-Config').menu({
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left+7 top+25"
    }
});
```

my problem is that the icon for submenu(like an arrow) is not visible on the aConfig or on the ulMenu-Config. Where is my bug?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Provide this info in your question

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#ulMenu-Config').menu({`?

Comment: my css is the default jquery-ui-1.10.3.css which comes with standard jQuery

Comment: Have you tried adding an icon line in the menu like they do in the documentation? $( ".selector" ).menu({ icons: { submenu: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" } });

Comment: yes @TimSPQR , it makes no sense

Comment: oh, i found the matter... i should at first set texts of <a> elements and then apply the constructor of the menu...(like this)
$('#aConfig').text('sometxt');
$('#ulMenu-Config').menu();

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. In my case I'd taken a local copy of the css (so I could fiddle with it a bit), but had failed to realise it had relative paths to the .png files containing the icons. As the css was no longer being served from the same place, and I hadn't copied the .pngs, the links where broken.